# Mongoose Slice Not Limiting Array Size

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm working on an application and am having an issue with Mongoose limiting array size on update. I'm not too familiar with MongoDB or Mongoose but I'm hoping this project will grow my knowledge. I tried a few other solutions I queried on SOF but none appeared to work for me. Here is my breakdown of the problem...

**Library**: Mongoose 5.7.7

**Summary**: In a document of logs, I wish to keep only the 10 latest logs with the older being pushed off the array.

**Issue**: With the current query I have, the slice appears not to be limiting the number of documents. The array just continues to grow.

```
ActivityLog.updateOne(
  { guild },
  {
    $push: {
      logs: {
        $each: [{ ...log }]
      },
      $slice: -10
    }
  },
  { upsert: true }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might actually be more of a problem in your implementation. Here's the basic thing in practical usage to show that it does indeed work:

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
const options = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };

mongoose.set("debug", true);
mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);

const demoSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Number,
  fifo: [Number]
},{ _id: false });

const Demo = mongoose.model('Demo', demoSchema, 'demo');

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, options);

    await Promise.all(
      Object.values(conn.models).map(m => m.deleteMany())
    );

    let counter = 0;

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      setInterval(async () => {
        try {
          let result = await Demo.findByIdAndUpdate(
            1,
            { "$push": { "fifo": { "$each": [counter], "$slice": -3 } } },
            { upsert: true, new: true }
          );

          log(result);
        } catch(e) {
          reject(e)
        }
        counter++;
      }, 2000)
    );


  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }

})()
```

On a few iterations ( and using `-3` for brevity here ) you would see:

```
Mongoose: demo.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: demo.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: 1 }, { '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 }, '$push': { fifo: { '$each': [ 0 ], '$slice': -3 } }}, { upsert: true, remove: false, projection: {}, returnOriginal: false })
{
  "fifo": [
    0
  ],
  "_id": 1,
  "__v": 0
}
Mongoose: demo.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: 1 }, { '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 }, '$push': { fifo: { '$each': [ 1 ], '$slice': -3 } }}, { upsert: true, remove: false, projection: {}, returnOriginal: false })
{
  "fifo": [
    0,
    1
  ],
  "_id": 1,
  "__v": 0
}
Mongoose: demo.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: 1 }, { '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 }, '$push': { fifo: { '$each': [ 2 ], '$slice': -3 } }}, { upsert: true, remove: false, projection: {}, returnOriginal: false })
{
  "fifo": [
    0,
    1,
    2
  ],
  "_id": 1,
  "__v": 0
}
Mongoose: demo.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: 1 }, { '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 }, '$push': { fifo: { '$each': [ 3 ], '$slice': -3 } }}, { upsert: true, remove: false, projection: {}, returnOriginal: false })
{
  "fifo": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "_id": 1,
  "__v": 0
}
Mongoose: demo.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: 1 }, { '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 }, '$push': { fifo: { '$each': [ 4 ], '$slice': -3 } }}, { upsert: true, remove: false, projection: {}, returnOriginal: false })
{
  "fifo": [
    2,
    3,
    4
  ],
  "_id": 1,
  "__v": 0
}
Mongoose: demo.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: 1 }, { '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 }, '$push': { fifo: { '$each': [ 5 ], '$slice': -3 } }}, { upsert: true, remove: false, projection: {}, returnOriginal: false })
{
  "fifo": [
    3,
    4,
    5
  ],
  "_id": 1,
  "__v": 0
}
Mongoose: demo.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: 1 }, { '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 }, '$push': { fifo: { '$each': [ 6 ], '$slice': -3 } }}, { upsert: true, remove: false, projection: {}, returnOriginal: false })
{
  "fifo": [
    4,
    5,
    6
  ],
  "_id": 1,
  "__v": 0
}
```

So this does indeed keep an array of the specified `$slice` length and from the end of the array as due to the negative, both growing the array to the set size and then removing all but the last added members.

Comment: I did spin up a small project to see it work. You mentioned it may be the way I implemented it, do you have any insight or details on that?

Comment: @Rykuno I would believe "the insight" would be the example of working code in front of you that you commented on. That was the whole point. Works as designed, as the answer demonstrates.

Comment: I get that your example works. But for our implementation I was wondering what the issue is and why it's not slicing :). "This might actually be more of a problem in your implementation". <-- I'm looking for clarification on this I believe, sorry for the miscommunication. I'll be working on it more today so I'll update if I find a solution

Comment: Went ahead and posted as accepted answer since I used it to solve my problem. My issue was a simple bracket. The $slice should have been within the same object as the $each operator. Figures it was something that simple.